# Best performing stocks in given year

Tags: historical-data, bloomberg

Is there a function in Bloomberg that allows the user to search the best performing stocks for a given year, say 2011, in any given stock exchange?

For example, I want to see the best performing stocks in 2011 for all stocks listed on the NYSE.

Also, is there a function that allows me to specify a time frame, say 5/5/2011 to 5/5/2012, and see the best performing stocks from that specific time frame?

Comment: Have you tried HELP HELP? Also if there is no function you can do that fairly easily in Excel.

Answer (score 1):

For each major index, Bloomberg has functions that will give you the best performers for each relevant period; past week, past month, past quarter, past year, etc.

I would take one of these "runs," and then re-set the start and end dates to the ones that you want.